# SQL Query SUM with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having

I'm having some difficulties finding the good query I need, looking for help.
After multiple JOIN and a lot of WHERE, I have this columns and values :

```
+---------+----------+--------+-------+
| id_test | quantity | price  |  fee  |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+
| "1-3"   |        1 | 33.52  | 29.00 |
| "1-5"   |        1 | 33.52  | 29.00 |
| "1-6"   |        1 | 33.52  | 29.00 |
| "1-8"   |        1 | 86.49  | 29.00 |
| "19-1"  |        1 | 176.54 | 29.00 |
| "19-4"  |        1 | 176.54 | 29.00 |
| "19-5"  |        4 | 176.54 | 29.00 |
| "19-6"  |        1 | 199.47 | 29.00 |
| "19-6"  |        1 | 176.54 | 29.00 |
| "20-10" |        2 | 72.67  | 29.00 |
| "20-11" |        2 | 18.95  | 29.00 |
| "20-9"  |        1 | 22.13  | 29.00 |
+---------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Each id_test object as a quantity, a price and a fee. I would like to SUM everything so to have a global price : (quantity*price)+fee
The thing is, and that's where I'm stuck, the fee has to be added only once by id_test. Yet, I have here two id_test "19-6".

If I SUM everything I have 1827.67 (price*quantity) + 348 (fee).

Since I have two "19-6", I need 1827.67 (price*quantity) + 319 (fee).

How would you do in SQL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Common Table Expressions (CTE)

Assuming your data in "data" table:

```
with total_fee as (
    select distinct id_test, fee from data
),
total_price as (
    select distinct id_test, sum(quantity) quantity, sum(price) price 
    from data
    group by id_test
)


select sum(b.price*quantity) quantity, sum(a.fee) fee
from total_fee a
left join total_price b
on a.id_test = b.id_test
```

Answer (score 0):

Only once by id_test means you have to take distinct id_test. If 29.00 is a fixed static value, you can take the distinct id_test and multiply it by 29.00

You can Insert the values of the above query to a temporary table ( #tempTable). Then your above output values will be temporary saved to a table

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(id_test) * 29.00 AS fee
FROM
  #tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put id_test, (quantity * price) & fee in a temporary table.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT
    id_test,
    (quantity * price) AS total,
    fee 
FROM
table
)
```

2. Now add the total for every id

```
WITH cte2 AS (
SELECT SUM(total) + fee AS total_id
 FROM cte1
 GROUP BY id_test
)
```

3. Now find the total sum

```
 SELECT SUM(total_id) AS SUM
 FROM cte1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(quantity * price),
       (select sum(fee)
        from (select distinct(id_test), fee
        from sales) as fees)
from sales;
```

I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aa13a/11) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) + SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN fee END) AS RESULT
FROM   (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition BY id_test) rn 
        FROM   test) m
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9975619f35b528df05e35e238fee7ac)

*OUTPUT*

```
Result
2146.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select sum(price * quantity) + fee
from t
group by id_test, fee;
```

If you have *different* fees for the same test, you might want:

```
select sum(price * quantity) + avg(fee)
from t
group by id_test;
```